# clearInterval() From inside of an interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

If I have a setInterval like this, how can I make the clearInterval stop the looping?

```js
setInterval(function(){
  clearInterval()
}, 10000)
```

Or is there some other way to break the loop from within the loop
This is inside of a for loop

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  As presented, smells like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I am setting multiple intervals inside of a for statement to add and change values inside of a mysql db

Answer (score 3):

You can set `intervalId` and pass it as `parameter` of `clearInterval` as

```js
let intervalId = setInterval(function(){
  alert('interval')
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without setting the interval as a variable, as I will have multiple inside a for statement

Answer (score 0):

This boilerplate code will allow you to use `clearInterval()` as you intend:

```js
const _setInterval = setInterval;
setInterval = function (cb, ms) {
  let id = null;
  const _cb = cb;
  cb = () => _cb(() => clearInterval(id));
  id = _setInterval(cb, ms);
  return id;
}
```

For example, this code sets a 1 second interval to log `'foo'` then clears itself:

```js
const _setInterval = setInterval;
setInterval = function (cb, ms) {
  let id = null;
  const _cb = cb;
  cb = () => _cb(() => clearInterval(id));
  id = _setInterval(cb, ms);
  return id;
}

setInterval(function (clearInterval) {
  console.log('foo');
  clearInterval();
}, 1_000);
```

As currently written, it will work for anonymous functions that take zero arguments.  It won't work for other functions because it changes their first argument to `clearInterval` and doesn't pass any other arguments.